# AWS Cognito OAuth: Login request failure

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, restsharp

I want to skip AWS Cognito's Hosted UI for login/authorization. However, when I try to consume the login end point to fetch authorization-code, I'm slapped with **MethodNotAllowed** response. As per AWS documentation, the login end-point accepts "**Get**" requests only. Based on my research on this topic, I figured it was possible to use "**Post**" method with login credentials for the login end point (Thanks to AWS documentation).

Can someone help please me figure out the issue?

**AWS Pool Settings:**
[AWS Pool Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3baVz.png)

**C# Code:**
I'm using RestSharp as the HTTP client.

```
        private static void CognitoOAuthSignIn(string username, string password)
        {
            var CLIENT_ID = "<client_id>";
            var RESPONSE_TYPE = "code";
            var REDIRECT_URI = "https://www.google.com";
            var SCOPE = "openid";
            var AUTH_DOMAIN = "https://<domain_name>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com";
            var USERNAME = username;
            var PASSWORD = password;

            RestClient client = null;

            // 1. Get XSRF Code
            var csrfRequestUrl = $"{AUTH_DOMAIN}/oauth2/authorize?response_type={RESPONSE_TYPE}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&scope={SCOPE}";
            var csrfRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            client = new RestClient(csrfRequestUrl);
            client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            IRestResponse csrfResp = client.Execute(csrfRequest);
            var cookie = client.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri(AUTH_DOMAIN));
            var code = cookie.Split(';')[0].Substring(11);

            // 2. Make login request
            var loginRequestUrl = $"{AUTH_DOMAIN}/login?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type={RESPONSE_TYPE}&scope={SCOPE}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}";
            client = new RestClient(loginRequestUrl);
            client.DefaultParameters[0].Value = "*/*"; // Setting "Accept" header
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Cookie", $"csrf-state=; csrf-state-legacy=; XSRF-TOKEN={code}");

            var authCodeRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            authCodeRequest.AddParameter("_csrf", code, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            authCodeRequest.AddParameter("username", USERNAME, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            authCodeRequest.AddParameter("password", PASSWORD, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            authCodeRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.None;
            IRestResponse authCodeResp = client.Execute(authCodeRequest);
            Console.WriteLine(authCodeResp.StatusCode); //returns MethodNotAllowed
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered to use the AWS SDK to do the login? In that way you would skip the Hosted UI with no need to consume the login API. We had a similar requirement (skip AWS Cognito Hosted UI) in a project and the AWS SDK is working fine for us.

Comment: @HenriqueDroog Signing in using AWS SDK only adds the admin-scope to the access token, despite the fact I have not attached admin scope with the client I'm trying to sign in with. This does not work for us because we need app-client specific scopes to authorize user access on various API routes. This issue has been discussed here and it seems like a design limitation https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=266827

Comment: that is indeed true, AWS SDK is not the way to go if you need the scopes other than admin scope.